# HomeBrew Formula : Download two URL packages

Tags: homebrew

I need to get nginx compiled with the file upload package. The module doesn't come as part of the default nginx brew formula. It appears brew formulas are based off one download pkg, see below

```
class Nginx < Formula
  homepage 'http://nginx.org/'
  url 'http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.0.tar.gz'
  md5 'a02ef93d65a7031a1ea3256ad5eba626'

  devel do
    url 'http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.3.0.tar.gz'
    md5 'b02e171c4a088aa9a5ab387943ce08eb'
  end
```

How can I download the bellow in a subfolder, say nginx/contrib ?

```
url 'http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/download/nginx_upload_module-2.2.0.tar.gz'
md5 '2681a6167551830a23336fa41bc539a1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a "subformula". You would stick this class definition in the Nginx formula file:

```
class NginxUploadModule < Formula
  url 'http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/download/nginx_upload_module-2.2.0.tar.gz'
  md5 '2681a6167551830a23336fa41bc539a1'
end
```

and then in the `install` method of the Nginx formula, you would do something like

```
NginxUploadModule.new.brew do
  (buildpath/'where/you/want/the/files').install Dir['*']
end
```

adjusting the path accordingly.

There are a number of examples of this in the core Homebrew repository; grepping for "new.brew" should give you quite a few.

Answer (score 4):

From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/example-formula.rb

```
# Additional downloads can be defined as resources and accessed in the
# install method. Resources can also be defined inside a stable, devel, or
# head block. This mechanism replaces ad-hoc "subformula" classes.
resource "additional_files" do
  url "https://example.com/additional-stuff.tar.gz"
  sha1 "deadbeef7890123456789012345678901234567890"
end

# Additional downloads can be defined as resources (see above).
# The stage method will create a temporary directory and yield
# to a block.
resource("additional_files").stage { bin.install "my/extra/tool" }
```

Comment: Links seems to be broken now.

Comment: new link: https://github.com/syhw/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/example-formula.rb